# how to search for a matching name

Tags: javascript, for-loop, web-scraping, puppeteer

names contains a extracted name from a page after webscraping but i want to check if my search name exist in the name found after scraping, have used includes and indexof but none worked.

```
try{
  for(let name of names){
    if(name.includes(find_name)){
      console.log("got a match!")
      await page.goto(name.link)
      await sleep(5000);
    }
  }
}catch(e){
  console.log('could not check for match', e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that many ways, I mostly use two way for simple string search using str.search like in your case -

```
if (name.search(find_name)) {
   console.log("got a match!")
   await page.goto(name.link)
   await sleep(5000);
}
```

In above if it finds than it will give you position of the string, if not find than -1.

Or you can strict search like this -

```
var search = new RegExp(find_name , 'i'); // search term 
let searchedNameList = names.filter(name => search.test(name));
for (let name of searchedNameList) {
   await page.goto(name.link)
   await sleep(5000);
}
```

Above will give you the all the name list that contains you `find_name` than you can loop on searchedNameList like -
you can also use async/await like -

```
for await (let name of names) {}
```

Hop this helps.